# Does $2^{O(n)} $ mean $O(2^n)$? If not, what does $2^{O(n)} $ mean?

Tags: notation, asymptotics

In [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/asymptotic_analysis.htm) "tutorial", in the end, they say exponential asymptotic notation is $2^{O(n)} $.

Is $2^{O(n)} $ the same thing as $O(2^n)$? Is there any reason to notate it that way?

According to one of the answers, they are different. But then according to the "tutorial", $O(f(n))$ is a set. So how is the expression $2^{O(n)} $ meaningful?

(Specifically they define $O(f(n)) = \{ g(n) :$ exists $c \gt 0 $ and $n_0 \gt 0 $ such that $f(n) \leq c*g(n)$ for all $n \gt n_0$).

Comment: $f(n)=2^{O(n)}$ means $\log_2 f(n)=O(n).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ is $2^{O(n)}$ if and only if there is a constant $C$ such that for all $n$ large enough we have $f(n)\le 2^{Cn}$.

We can think of the $O$ notation as decribing a family of functions. So, $2^{O(n)}$ would be the family of functions satisfying the requirements just indicated.

In contrast, a function $f$ is $O(2^n)$ if and only if there is a constant $K$ such that for all $n$ large enough we have $f(n)\le K 2^n$.

It should be clear that $O(2^n)\subset 2^{O(n)}$, that is, any function that is $O(2^n)$ is also $2^{O(n)}$. The converse fails, however: consider $f(n)=2^{2n}$.

Comment: Would it make sense to use "composite" of big-O notation for functions other than $2^n$ too? ie. $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $g( O(n) )$ for a real function $g$ iff there's a constant $C$ such that for all $n$ large enugh we have $f(n) \leq g( Cn ) $ ?

Comment: Sure, that would be the natural interpretation of the notation. Of course, if you are using it in a writing of your own, it may be best to first remind the reader of its meaning, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Shouldn't $2^{O(n)}$ include a positive lower bound on $f$ as well?

Comment: @Umberto It is a matter of convention. Sure, some sources say that $f$ is $O(g)$ if and only if $|f(n)|\le C g(n)$ for some $C$ and all $n$ large enough. In that case, yes, we need some such lower bound as well (in the form: $f$ is $O(2^n)$ if and only if $|f(n)|\le 2^{Cn}$ for some $C$ and all large $n$). In many settings, though, all functions are assumed positive, and so the inclusion of the absolute value is redundant. It depends on the context.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't the same.  $2^{3n}$ is $2^{O(n)}$ but not $O(2^n)$

Comment: Hmm makes sense. What is the meaning of $2^{O(n)} $ then? According to their definition $O(f(n))$ is a set. How can $2$ to the power of a set be meaningful in this context?

Comment: I see that Andrés E. Caicedo has already addressed this.